# convert xml to json for each microservice or use a converter microservice?

Tags: json, xml

I'm looking to create an application using several microservices.  The overall application can accept both XML and json formatted requests.
Which option would be best:

1) Accept XML and json to each microservice?

2) Write a convertor microservice which converts XML to json and forwards json to each microservice which would only need to handle json.

3) Run 2 instances of each microservice, one which accepts XML and one which accepts json.

4) anything I'm not considering?